# Опечатка в описании привилегии "Правка вопросов и ответов"

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка, привилегии

В [описании](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) привилегии "Правка вопросов и ответов" нарушена связь между подлежащим и сказуемым:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]