# Собираем все дефекты из справки в одном месте!

Tags: дефект, предложение, локализация, справка

Справка давно не обновлялась. Таким образом со справкой есть проблемы:

- В справке есть незначительный дефекты оформления, опечатки и так далее.
- В справке есть устаревшая информация.
- Некоторые страницы не переведены вообще.

Поэтому я предлагаю собрать здесь все эти дефекты. Все в одном месте. Ведь тогда мы:

- Сможем понять, сколько в справке нужно исправить.
- Сможем это исправить и в последствии попросить сотрудника отредактировать (сотруднику нужно будет лишь скопировать изменения и вставимть их, ведь сотрудник русского может не знать).

На этот вопрос я планирую создать 4 общих ответа:

1. [Мелкие дефекты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12605/532877).
2. [Страницы с устаревшей информацией](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12603/532877).
3. [Страницы без перевода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12604/532877)
4. [Неверные ссылки и картинки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12745/532877) (ссылки на метки, вроде [какая-то-метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) — это в мелкие дефекты).
5. [Прочее дефекты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12609/532877), которые не подходят по смыслу в остальные общие ответы.

#### **Дополнение**

Исправление дефектов в справке можно разделить на несколько этапов:

1. Составления списка дефектов (это тут). Дефекты как и найденные ранее и опубликованные на мете, так  и замеченные вами недавно. Основную часть дефектов вроде как собрали. Если что, всегда можно дописать.
2. Приведение этого списка в единый и простой вид.
3. Переписывание/перевод статьей справки, которые в этом нуждаются. Это в отдельных постах на нашей мете, но из этого топика обязательно должны быть ссылки на переписанные/переведённые статьи. Этот этап начат.
4. Нужно будет попросить сотрудника вставить уже исправленные статьи справки.

#### Дополнение 2

На данный момент полностью переписаны 3 статьи, переведены полностью — 5, частично — 1 и ещё 1 должна быть просто удалена. Сделал [версию для сотрудника на английском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13149/532877).

**P.S**: Чтобы отредактировать общие ответы, нужно всего 100 баллов репутации. Пожалуйста, дополните списки!

Comment: Можно просто отфильтровать вопросы по меткам [дефект] и [справка]. Если меток нет, добавить.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не про всё есть на мете. + Тогда на проблему будет обращено меньше внимания. И гораздо удобней, когда есть красивый, уже отфильтрованый список актуальных дефектов.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight народ в чате про справку много говорит. Походу, собираются достучаться до сотрудника и справку править. Вот я список дефектов и выложил.

Comment: *"Есть у нас такая проблема .. Таким образом .. есть две проблемы .. список из 3 пунктов"* - забавно как они плодятся прямо на глазах )

Comment: Неплохо бы тогда добиться понимания, как работает механизм сообщений о дефектах на мете. По идее, все должно быть просто, участник создал вопрос, администрация его видит и реагирует. Непонятно, почему нужны какие-то "письма Катюше". Корень проблемы в том, что из администраторов теперь нет никого, понимающего по русски? Тогда может надо сразу на басурманском составлять этот список дефектов?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight "Тогда может надо сразу на басурманском составлять этот список дефектов" - страницы справки-то на русском. Лучше создать список дефектов, в создать ещё один пост, но уже с исправлением дефектов (или не создавать отдельного поста, здесь же привести исправление) и попросить сотрудника просто скопировать новый тект справки отсюда (русского-то сотрудники не знают).

Comment: А какая судьба этого топика, если все дефекты разом будут исправлены? Честно говоря, долговременной перспективы в этом не вижу, как-будто бы логичнее письмом отправить человеку, который может это исправить, а если такого нет - то и топик теряет смысл

Comment: @Павел смысл этого топика - обратить внимание на дефекты. Потом (я очень надеюсь) сообщество разместит на мете исправленные страницы и англоязычному сотруднику останется лишь скопировать с меты исправленные страницы уже в справку.

Comment: Нужно поправить страницу "Почему я был отстранен от очередей проверок". Там куча опечаток. Мне просто лень править общий ответ, добавьте там сами)

Comment: И пунктуационные ошибки там тоже есть.

Comment: @Глеб я внимательно прочитаю эту страницу в ближайшее время. Кстати, некоторые ошибки уже занесены в общий ответ.

Answer (score 5):

## Мелкие дефекты

#### Опечатки

- [Постоянный пользователь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) - [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12053/).
  "ваш**у** аватар" нужно заменить на "ваш аватар":

> Как другие могут увидеть вашу развернутую карточку пользователя? Если кто-либо из участников сообщества желает просмотреть вашу карточку, он может в вопросе, ответе или списке пользователей навести курсор на **вашу** аватар, и поверх нее появится развернутая карточка с дополнительной информацией. Она также называется развернутой карточкой.

- [Очередь проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) - [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12021/).  "процессу проверке" нужно заменить на "процессу проверки":

> В очереди запоздалых ответов появляются ответы новых пользователей на вопросы, заданные гораздо раньше. У новых ответов будет гораздо меньше просмотров, чем было у тех, которые появились вскоре публикации вопроса, и благодаря процессу проверк**е** можно гарантировать, что качество данных ответов будет не хуже.

- [Инструменты модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) - [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11062/).  Опечатка в разделе "Доступ к инструментам модератора". Нужно заменить "радел" на "раз**д**ел":

> Можно довольно быстро понять, что **радел** «инструменты» содержит только дополнительную информацию!

- [Правка вопросов и ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) - [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11805/).  Опечатка в самом первом абзаце. Нужно заменить "эти правки не будет" на "эти правки не буд**у**т".

> Мы верим в силу коллективной правки. Это означает, что после того, как вы набрали достаточно баллов репутации, мы доверяем вам право редактировать в системе все, что угодно, и **эти правки не будет** попадать на проверку. Причем правило действительно не только для ваших сообщений, а для сообщений всех участников!

- [Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Тут какое-то несогласование...

  Сейчас:

  > #### Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?
  >
  > Совершенно точно стоит!

  Должно быть:

  > #### Стоит ли отвечать на свой собственный вопрос?
  >
  > Совершенно точно стоит!
- [Почему я был отстранен от очередей проверок?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-suspensions).
  Опечатка "если мен**а** отстранили". Должно быть "если меня отстранили":

> #### Что мне делать, если мен**а** отстранили?

#### Проблемы с оформлением

- [Что такое репутация? Как можно её заработать (и потерять)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) - [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12358/).

На странице должны были быть заголовки, но переводящий статью забыл поставить пробел между `###` и самим заголовком, в результате получилось это:

> ###Репутация повышается в следующих случаях:
>
> - .....
> - .....

> ###Репутация понижается в следующих случаях:
>
> - .....
> - .....

- [Почему я был отстранен от очередей проверок?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-suspensions). Стоит добавить ссылку на метку (заменить `[очередь-проверок]` на [очередь-проверок](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba)).
- [Что такое Мета и как она работает?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Заменить `[поддержка]`, `[дефект]`, `[предложение]` и `[обсуждение]` на мета-метки [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0), [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82), [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

#### Устарели отдельные слова

- [Почему Дух сообщества удалил мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions). "Копия" следует заменить на "дубликат":

> Если вопрос был закрыт более 9 дней назад и ...
>
> - был закрыт с причиной отличной от **“копия”**;

- [Почему некоторые вопросы отмечаются как дубликаты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) - [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11894/). Конкретно мелкий дефект состоит в том, что [копия] нужно заменить на [дубликат]:

> Если вопрос помечен как дубликат, это может быть частью [процедуры закрытия вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), с тем исключением, что когда вопрос закрывается как дубликат, в его заголовок вносится состояние **«[копия]»**, а не «[закрыт]».

#### Неправильный перевод

- [Привилегии - Инструменты модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

  Сейчас:

  > Получив привилегию «Инструменты модератора» вы сможете:
  >
  > - просматривать удалённые сообщения;
  > - *голосовать за закрытие и повторное открытие вопросов;*
  > - ...

  Оригинал:

  > You can...
  >
  > - View deleted posts
  > - *Cast delete and undelete votes on questions*
  > - ...

  Должно быть:

  > Получив привилегию «Инструменты модератора» вы сможете:
  >
  > - просматривать удалённые сообщения;
  > - *голосовать за удаление и восстановление вопросов;*
  > - ...

Comment: На странице "очередь проверок" есть еще опечатка: "скорое всего" вместо "скорее всего". Надо добавить.

Comment: @Глеб эту страницу вообще полностью переписать надо. Когда буду это делать, учту. Если хотите, можете добавить в "мелкие дефекты".

Answer (score 4):

## Страницы с устаревшей информацией

- [Что такое очереди проверок?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro) — сказано про очередь первых сообщений, но  эта очередь уже разбита на две: "Первые вопросы" и "Первые ответы". К тому же там ещё сказано про очереди "Сортировка" и "Помощь и улучшение", а они есть только на enSO.
- [Как пользоваться очередью первых сообщений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-posts) — этой очереди уже нет. У нас есть страницы справки [про очередь "первые вопросы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions) и [про "первые ответы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers) (правда, они без перевода). [В справке enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-queues) тоже статьи про эти очереди располагаются отдельно. **Решение: статью про очередь "первые сообщения" удалить, перевести страницы про "первые вопросы" и "первые ответы" ([переводы уже есть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13135/532877))**
- [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) — [описание дефектов и проблем](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13140/532877). Кратко: с тех про появилось много ИИ, кроме chatGPT. К тому же, статья была написана в спешке, поэтому получилась сжатой и непонятной. **[Новая версия данной статьи на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13141/532877)**.
- [Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»? Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) — [описание дефектов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12931/532877). **[Новая версия данной статьи на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12932/532877)**.
- [Общие сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) — [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8506/). **[Новая версия данной статьи на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13079/532877)**. Устарели эти три пункта, их нужно убрать:

> В этих случаях, мы верим, что сообщение де-факто является общим:
>
> - тело сообщение было отредактировано минимум 5 различными участниками;
> - сообщение было отредактировано 10 раз автором;
> - вопрос получает более 30 ответов;

Поскольку это почти все элементы маркированного списка, то последний элемент нужно преобразовать в обычное предложение.
Кроме этого есть ещё некоторые недочёты [неправильный скриншот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12745/532877), несогласования и очепятки.

Answer (score 4):

## Страницы без перевода

#### Очереди проверок

- [How do I use the First answers queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers) — **есть [полностью готовый перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13137/532877)**.
- [How do I use the Close votes queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-close) — есть [перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11114/11120#11120), но надо проверить его на актуальность, ибо он был сделан довольно давно.
- [How do I use the Reopen votes queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-reopen) — есть [перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11121/532877), но надо проверить его на актуальность, ибо он был сделан довольно давно.
- [How do I use the First questions queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions) — **есть [полностью готовый перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13136/532877).**
- [How do I use the Late answers queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-late-) — есть [перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11114/11122#11122), но надо проверить на актуальность, он сделан довольно давно.

#### Репутация и модерация

- [Who are the staff, and what is their role here?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/staff) — **есть [полностью готовый перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12631/)**.
- [What are DMCA Takedowns and why was my contribution removed?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dmca-takedown) — **есть [полностью готовый перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12620)**.
- [Moderator Agreement policies](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies) — **есть [полностью готовый перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12630/532877).**

#### Моя учётная запись

- [When does Stack Exchange ask for my cookie consent?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/cookie-reconsent)
- [How do I use Saves?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/saves)

Comment: Откатил последнюю правку, так как данная тема только для отсутствующих переводов в справке. По переводам на сайте создавайте отдельные темы.

Comment: Вот тут написано, что "*осталось только добавить уже готовый перевод*". А кто его будет добавлять, когда, и будет ли вообще?

Comment: @wchistow тот же, кто и всё остальное. То есть сотрудник. Вообще-то сотрудника можно  позвать, и он должен прийти. Недавно так делали, когда выборы проводились.

Answer (score 3):

## Прочие дефекты

- [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12396/). Раздел "Благодарите за ответы на ваши вопросы" в статье "Как задать хороший вопрос?" явно лишний. Вот этот абзац нужно просто убрать:

> #### Благодарите за ответы на ваши вопросы
>
> Ваше простое искреннее «спасибо» очень ценно, но это не все, чем вы можете отблагодарить ответившего — проголосуйте за ответы, которые вам больше всего помогли, и, по возможности, отвечайте на вопросы других участников.

- [Меньше рекламы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) - [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7761/).
  Нет одного абзаца, который есть на [аналогичной странице справки на еnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads):

> #### But what if I still want to see those ads?
>
> But what if I still want to see those ads?
> If you decide that you really like seeing banner ads because they're useful or interesting to you, then you can disable this privilege in your profile. Click on "Edit Profile & Settings", then click on "Preferences". There will be an option for re-enabling these ads, should you wish: 
> [image: картинка из абзаца справки] 
> We want to emphasize that you should only re-enable banner ads if you want to see them, not because you're trying to support us financially. In fact, it doesn't really do us any good to show you ads for products that you don't want to engage with. So make the decision that's best for you, and that's the one that's best for us too.

**[Переведённый на мете абзац](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13041/532877).**

Answer (score 2):

## Неверные ссылки и картинки

#### Cсылки

- [Как использовать очередь проверок «Сообщения низкого качества»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) - проблема с одной ссылкой. Сама ссылка ведёт туда, куда и должна, вот только описание ссылки не переведено.

Сейчас:

> - Рекомендовать закрытие или Закрыть, если вы считаете, что вопрос должен быть закрыт (см. [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)).

Должно быть:

> - Рекомендовать закрытие или Закрыть, если вы считаете, что вопрос должен быть закрыт (см. [Что означает статус вопроса "закрыт"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)).

- [Что такое метки и как их использовать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) - [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8549/).
  Ссылка на статью про мета-метки ведёт на английскую статью, хотя у нас есть на мете [перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/).

Сейчас:

```
Не используйте [мета-метки](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) в вопросах.
```

Должно быть:

```
Не используйте [мета-метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/) в вопросах.
```

#### Картинки

- [Общие сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) - [описание дефекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8865/). **[Новая версия данной статьи на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13079/532877)**. Стоит заменить скриншот с enSO на скриншот с ruSO. Вот новый скриншот:

> [image: Новый скриншот]

- [Почему я был отстранен от очередей проверок?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-suspensions). Стоит заменить скриншот с enSO на скриншот с ruSO.

Answer (score 1):

## Version on English for a staff

- Help article [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) should be replaced on [this](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13141/532877).
- Help article [Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»? Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) should be replaced on [this](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12932/532877).
- Help article [Общие сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) should be replaced on [this](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13079/532877).
- In help article [Меньше рекламы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) there is not the subparagraph "But what if I still want to see those ads?". [There is translation of this subparagraph](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13041/532877).
- Help article [Как пользоваться очередью первых сообщений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-posts) should be deleted.
- Help article [How do I use the First questions queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions) should get [translation](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13136/532877).
- Help article [How do I use the First answers queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers) should get [translation](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13137/532877).
- Help article [Who are the staff, and what is their role here?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/staff) should get [translation](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12632/532877).
- Help article [What are DMCA Takedowns and why was my contribution removed?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dmca-takedown) should get [translation](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12621/532877).
- Help article [Moderator Agreement policies](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies) should get [translation](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12630/532877).