# Перевод страницы справки про Moderator Agreement policies

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

Оригинальная страница: [Moderator Agreement policies](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies).

Битые (?) ссылки в оригинале:

- [Stack Moderators Team](https://stackoverflow.com/help/moderator-private-team)
- [Учительской](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mod-tl)

Возможно, SE намеренно возвращают `404`, вместо `403`. Будет круто, если кто-то с ромбом проверит это.

Comment: _Будет круто, если кто-то с ромбом проверит это._ - 404

Comment: @aepot надо просто домен правильный выбрать. У нас `ru.` ромбы, поэтому ссылки другие. А эти для enSO. Они вполне рабочие.

Comment: Вот [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies) ссылки корректные. Всё относительно базового сайта.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ссылки поправил. Но для обычных участников `404`. Видимо, [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано]

Comment: С точки зрения ссылок - [так-задумано], да.

Comment: @Зонтик Страница справки про соглашение и само соглашение — это разные страницы

Answer (score 3):

## Политики Соглашения Модератора

---

Модераторы связаны [соглашением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement), в котором говорится, что они будут

> (...) соблюдать все другие официально объявленные политики для модераторов
> и пользователей.

В сети Stack Exchange существует множество FAQ и правил сообщества, но это утверждение применимо только к небольшому набору политик, которые определяются компанией и действуют по всей сети. Поскольку Соглашение Модератора должно быть относительно статичным и требует, чтобы модераторы принимали его повторно при каждом изменении, эти политики перечислены здесь и будут постоянно обновляться вне Соглашение Модератора. Если эти политики изменятся или будут добавлены новые, модераторы будут проинформированы об этих изменениях.

Для упрощения эта статья указывает модераторам на официальные политики, которых их просят придерживаться, за исключением [норм поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct), [условий использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) и [политики конфиденциальности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy), которые перечислены отдельно в cоглашении модератора.

#### Где я могу найти эти политики?

Упомянутые политики в настоящее время находятся на [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Все официальные политики на MSE будут опубликованы с меткой [[mod-agreement-policy]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy), которая предназначена только для персонала, и к ним будет применена блокировка, позволяющая редактировать эти политики только [сотрудниками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/staff).

Возможно, что политики могут появиться в других местах, например cправка или [блог](https://stackoverflow.blog/). Если это произойдет, ссылки на новые политики будут добавлены на эту страницу, чтобы их можно было легко найти.

#### Когда и как корпорация Stack Exchange внедряет новые политики?

Если возникнет необходимость в новой политике, сначала она будет написана и передана [совету модераторов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347104/introducing-the-moderator-council-and-its-first-pro-tempore-representatives). Затем она пройдёт через процесс обратной связи и возможных итераций, прежде чем будет представлена модераторам из [Stack Moderators Team](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/moderator-private-team). Затем эти будущие политики будут опубликованы на MSE и получат тег [mod-agreement-policy] для обозначения их статуса.

#### Политика отсутствует или больше не актуальна?

Иногда политика, помеченная в MSE или содержащаяся в приведённом выше списке, больше не актуальна — может, появилась новая, которая её заменяет, или изменилось что-то ещё, что делает её устаревшей. Иногда есть что-то, что может быть включено в список этих политик, но ещё не было включено.

В любом случае модераторы могут связаться с КМ в [Учительской](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mod-tl), чтобы мы могли обсудить, как действовать дальше. Если вы не являетесь модератором, отметьте тревогой соответствующее сообщение для привлечения внимания модератора и объясните проблему, и один из модераторов MSE привлечёт наше внимание.

#### Предназначена ли метка [mod-agreement-policy] на Meta Stack Exchange для всех политик и правил?

Нет. Метка не предназначено для свода всех правил.

Подавляющее большинство правил и политик в сети определяются сообществом и поддерживаются компанией. Эти правила часто варьируются в зависимости от сайта, а на некоторых вообще могут не применяться.  Кроме того, многие из таких правил, которые вы найдете, являются «лучшими практиками», определёнными на основе многолетнего опыта работы в качестве платформы вопросов и ответов.

Хотя мы поддерживаем правила сообщества, они не достигает той степени важности, чтобы мы рассматривали её соблюдение как часть соглашения модератора. Метка [mod-agreement-policy] будет использоваться только для самых важных политик, которые должны соблюдать модераторы.