# Перевод страницы справки "Who are the staff, and what is their role here?"

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

Оригинальная страница: [Who are the staff, and what is their role here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/staff)

Answer (score 2):

## Кто такие сотрудники и какова их роль здесь?

---

Сотрудники — это люди, нанятые корпорацией Stack Exchange для различных целей. Это оплачиваемые, не волонтёрские, должности. Хотя наиболее заметными сотрудниками часто являются те, кто входит в наши [команды по управлению сообществом и публичной платформой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349266/the-community-teams-stack-exchange-and-how-we-work-together), это лишь небольшая подгруппа сотрудников, которые поддерживают работу Stack Exchange.

### Как отличить сотрудника от остальных участников?

Сотрудники делятся на 2 категории:

- Обычный сотрудник: этих сотрудников больше всего. По большей части они являются постоянными
  пользователями. Рядом с их никнеймами в сообщениях и комментариях, а также на странице их профилей будет
  отображаться метка <kbd>Сотрудник</kbd>.
- Ромбовой сотрудник: это небольшая группа наших сотрудников. Как правило,
  разработчики, инженеры и члены команды сообщества нуждаются в
  особом доступе к инструментам модерации и содержимому. Они более
  заметны и имеют ромб (♦) рядом со своими пользовательскими именами, точно
  так же, как наши [избранные модераторы сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators), то есть рядом с их никнеймами кроме метки <kbd>Сотрудник</kbd> будет отображаться ещё и метка  <kbd>♦ Мод</kbd>.

Comment: ИМХО, "Как я могу идентифицировать сотрудника?" - не звучит.

Comment: @Зонтик "Как отличить сотрудника от остальных участников?"

Comment: @aepot да, мне тоже кажется, что так лучше.

Comment: @Зонтик с мобилы сижу, не буду править, так как неудобно одновременно в английский реф смотреть. Предлагаю вам правку внести.

Comment: @aepot на мете нельзя предлагать правки `=(` ("Правки-предложения для сообщений, не являющихся «общими», на Мете запрещены.")

Comment: @Зонтик ну тогда вперёд, ещё 494 репы настричь надо :)