# Разбираемся со статьями справки про очереди проверок, которые связаны с первыми сообщениями пользователей

Tags: дефект, статус-проверка, очередь-проверок, справка, первые-вопросы

Раньше существовала очередь проверок, которая называлась "первые сообщения". Теперь она разбита на две: "первые вопросы" и "первые ответы".

Со справкой по этим очередям проблема:

- У нас осталась [статья про очередь "первые сообщения"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-posts).
- Статьи про [первые вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions) и [первые ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers) не имеют перевода.

Поэтому предлагаю:

- Удалить статью про "первые сообщения" вовсе.
- Перевести статьи про "первые вопросы" и "первые ответы", что я и сделаю в ответах на этот пост. Кроме перевода нужно ещё добавить ссылки на некоторые статьи из нашей справки, где это уместно.

**P.S**: ответы с переводами будут сделаны общими, то есть для свободного редактирования нужно всего 100 баллов репутации. Улучшайте переводы, если хотите! И ещё: прошу оценить их качество с помощью голосования и оставить замечания в комментариях.

Answer (score 2):

## Как пользоваться очередью «Первые вопросы»?

*Очередь становится доступной при достижении 500 баллов репутации*.

Очередь [первые вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions) содержит вопросы от новых участников, которые могут не знать правила сайта: как задавать качественный вопрос, какие вопросы по теме, а какие — нет.
Цель этой очереди — обратить особое внимание на вопросы от новых участников, которые, скорее всего, нуждаются в улучшении.

### Процесс проверки

- Нажмите <kbd>Выглядит нормально</kbd>, если вопрос хорош в текущем виде.
- Выберете <kbd>Править</kbd>, если нужна правка пунктуации, орфографии или форматирования.
- Используйте опцию <kbd>Оставить отзыв</kbd>, если вопрос нуждается в правке от автора. Вы можете выбрать один из шаблонных комментариев или оставить свой собственный. Шаблонные комментарии можно отправлять от имени [Духа Сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/).
- Выберете <kbd>Другие действия</kbd>, если требуется выполнить несколько действий или вы поставили на сообщение [тревогу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- Нажмите <kbd>Пропустить</kbd>, если вы не уверены, что стоит сделать.

Каждый вопрос проверяется только одним участником, поэтому будьте внимательны, и тщательно проверьте, отвечает ли сообщение требованиям сайта.

### Рекомендации по принятию решений

- Убедитесь, что основная часть вопроса находится в его теле, а не за пределами сайта: вопрос не должен терять смысла, даже если ссылки на другие ресурсы станут недоступными или будут изменены.
- Проверьте, что вопрос:

  - Понятен.
  - Включает в себя всю информацию, необходимую для ответа на него.
  - [По теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) сайта.
  - Предполагает ответы, основанные на фактах и цитатах, а не на мнениях.
  - Отражает стремление разобраться.
  - Содержит [метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), которые описывают его тему.
- Если уместно, оставьте подробный комментарий для запрашивания более подробной информации.
- Если вопрос похож на другой, который задавался ранее, проверьте, не является ли вопрос [дубликатом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).
- [Голосуйте «за»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) качественные вопросы, чтобы поощрить новых участников.
- Если в сообщении содержится спам или оскорбительный материал, поставьте на него [тревогу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- Рекомендуйте закрытие или голосуйте за закрытие, если вопрос требует этого. От том, какие вопросы следует закрывать, вы можете узнать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Рекомендуем так же прочитать [статью про редактирование сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing), чтобы понять, в каких случаях стоит воспользоваться правкой сообщений.

Answer (score 2):

## Как пользоваться очередью «Первые ответы»?

*Очередь становится доступной при достижении 500 баллов репутации*.

Очередь [первые ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) содержит ответы от новых участников, которые могут не знать правила сайта: как писать хорошие ответы и что комментарии ими не являются. Цель этой очереди — обратить особое внимание на ответы от новых участников, которые, скорее всего, нуждаются в улучшении.

### Процесс проверки

- Нажмите <kbd>Выглядит нормально</kbd>, если ответ хорош в текущем виде.
- Выберете <kbd>Править</kbd>, если нужна правка пунктуации, орфографии или форматирования.
- Используйте опцию <kbd>Оставить отзыв</kbd>, если ответ нуждается в правке от автора. Вы можете выбрать один из шаблонных комментариев или оставить свой собственный. Шаблонные комментарии можно отправлять от имени [Духа Сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/).
- Выберете <kbd>Другие действия</kbd>, если вы выполнили несколько действий или поставили на сообщение [тревогу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- Нажмите <kbd>Пропустить</kbd>, если вы не уверены, что стоит сделать.

Каждый ответ проверяется только одним участником, поэтому будьте внимательны и проверьте, что он не является комментарием к другому сообщению, не является "ответом-ссылкой" и не рекламирует товар/услугу.

### Рекомендации по принятию решений

- Убедитесь, что ответ является ответом, а не комментарием или новым вопросом.
- Просмотрите вкладку <kbd>Другие ответы</kbd> (если она есть), чтобы убедиться, что ответ уникален и не является копией другого.
- Проверьте, что сообщение не является «ответом-ссылкой»: ссылки должны лишь дополнять, а не заменять написанное.
- Если сообщение является спамом или содержит оскорбительные материалы, то поставьте на него [тревогу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Рекомендуем так же прочитать [статью про редактирование сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing), чтобы понять, в каких случаях стоит воспользоваться правкой сообщений.

Comment: В параграфе про "Нажмите Выглядит нормально" второе предложение явно лишнее.

Comment: И подраздел "править" куда-то съелся.

Comment: "ответ не состоит из одной лишь ссылки" — лучше "не ответ-ссылка". Ответы ссылки не всегда состоят из одной ссылки. Иногда бывает пару предложений бессмысленного сопроводительного текста.

Comment: @Глеб да, второе предложение в "выглядит нормально" - это был "осколок" от пункта "править". Спасибо за внимательность!

Comment: @Глеб переформулировал так: "*Проверьте, что сообщение не является "ответом-ссылкой": ссылки должны лишь дополнять, а не заменять написанное*."