# Хотим ли мы добавить напоминание в блок ввода ответа о недопустимости ответов, сгенерированных ИИ?

Tags: предложение, статус-проверка, ответы, генеративный-ии

На большом Stack Overflow в шапке формы ввода ответа есть напоминание о недопустимости ответов, сгенерированных ИИ:

> [image: Напоминание об AI]

Как вы считаете, стоит ли нам попросить аналогичную возможность? Или это наоборот приведёт к увеличения числа подобных ответов теми, кто раньше и не планировал это использовать?

Просьба выражать согласие или несогласие голосованием на вопросе. Если есть что сказать дополнительно, то, конечно же, публикуйте ваши ответы.

Связанный вопрос на MSE: [Add a warning about generative AI on other sites (only to sites which banned generative AI) of Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394512/339911)

Comment: Т.е. если такой текст вывешивать не надо, то поставить минус вопросу? (как-то странно, я всегда считал, что минусовые вопросы это обозначение, что тема не заслуживает внимания)

Comment: @avp да, именно так и предлагается реагировать на вопросы с меткой [meta-tag:предложение] (см. описание метки)

Comment: Короче, мы хотим, моя прелесть, хотим.

Comment: @Зонтик написал в служебный чатик сотруднику о нашем решении, надеюсь, в понедельник по Нью-Йорку что-нибудь ответят.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а про справку написали?

Comment: @Зонтик о том, что справку надо обновить? Я думаю, это сможем сделать следом, как станет понятно с баннером.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ сделал [версию на басурманском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13149/532877), о том, что должен сделать сотрудник. Пока только самое главное (т.е. статьи, которые надо полностью переписывать).

Comment: А как вы думает: следует ли создавать отдельный вопрос для голосования за формулировку надписи на баннере или же можно сделать здесь же? Или вообще голосовать не надо (тогда у нас не демократия)?

Comment: @Зонтик давай решать проблемы постепенно. Когда (и если) появится баннер, подумаем о формулировке. Пока даже не ясно, где она будет храниться. Ну или сотрудник сам поинтересуется, как она должна выглядеть. Демократии тут нет. Только [meta-tag:модераторский-произвол].

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427423/1328704), the results of the experiment on SO are currently being previewed to the moderators, and will be shared with the broader communities in early January — keep an eye on [the original MSO announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426353/1328704), and then on MSE for next steps for other network sites.

Comment: На мета-мете пишут, что все готово, и любой сайт может попросить себе такой баннер: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/353058

Comment: @HolyBlackCat так я здесь метку [meta-tag:status-review] как раз добавил с описанием. См. историю поста.

Comment: Те, кто читает правила, не будут постить фигню, а остальные будут продолжать постить не читая. Лучше бы добавили указание причины для минусования, и генерирование ответов - как одну из них. Либо автоматом вставляли в каждом вопросе автоматически сгенерированный ответ.

Comment: @user7860670 "добавили указание причины для минусования" из выпадающего списка? А то ведь у некоторых участников выданных минусов на порядок больше плюсов. Так и минусовать расхочется.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Из списка, благо уже почти готовые имеются http://idownvotedbecau.se

Answer (score 15):

**Я считаю, что баннер надо добавить** (и именно я до этого поднимал [тему](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394512/1346379) на MSE). Как мне кажется, многие из тех, кто публикуют ИИ-ответы, даже не подозревают, что это плохо. Конечно, будут товарищи, нарушающие это правило специально, посмотрев на баннер. Но таких товарищей нужно просто банить (ИИ-ответы отслеживаются легко визуально: если участник даёт по 10 - 20 ответов за час, они "водянистые" и по разным темам, то это точно ИИ).

Но некоторые моменты нужно доработать:

1. Придумать красивый перевод для предупреждения. Думаю, что имеет смысл устроить небольшое голосование. Пока предлагаю такой вариант:

   > **Предупреждение:** ответы, сгенерированные искусственным интеллектом, запрещены на StackOverFlow на русском. [Узнать больше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

2. Участникам с репутацией более 2k я бы дал возможность не показывать баннер после прочтения. Один раз прочитал    — можешь больше не видеть (но можешь и оставить). Потом заведу предложение на MSE.
3. Статью справки, на которую ссылается баннер, нужно переписать. Сейчас она просто никудышная. И читатель мало что узнаёт из неё нового. Для сравнения [статья на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy). Заодно предлагаю и справку вообще поправить, как раз на днях несколько страниц с английского перевёл (а некоторые переписывания/переводы ещё летом сделаны). Кстати, эту статью надо бы закрепить. 
   **UPD**: [новая версия статьи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13141/532877) готова, прошу высказать замечания и предложения (или даже самостоятельно внести изменения).

Comment: Могу помочь, кстати, с переводом справки.

Comment: Ссылка "Узнать больше" в примере перевода сообщения у ведёт на ваш вопрос на MSE, а должна, видимо, на справку.

Comment: @wchistow спасибо за замечание! Я, видимо, не скопировал не ту ссылку. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил в этот баннер предупреждение, что будет с такими ответами и участниками, их присылающими.

Comment: @wchistow возможно, это и стоит сделать (мой вариант баннера - не окончательный, это лишь первое, что в голову пришло), но я думаю, что это надо будет решить, когда устроим голосование за текст баннера.

Comment: @Глеб Готово: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13141/532877 Можете, пожалуйста, прочитать и высказать замечания (если есть) и поставить +, если всё хорошо?

Comment: @Зонтик, просмотрел, добавил коммент с замечаниями и поставил +. Мне самому отредактировать или вам удобнее это сделать?

Comment: @Глеб если вы можете и у вас есть желание, то отредактируйте сами., если нет - это сделаю я через часик.

Comment: @Зонтик, хорошо, сейчас сам поправлю.

Comment: Интересно, а как отнесутся к идее "перевода" плашки и статьи, если написать в плашке более универсальный текст, а статью сделать более общей. А то странно, что LLM объявляются основной проблемой мироздания.

Answer (score -5):

Не хотим (см. прикрепленное изображение). Лучше сделать более важные дела, например при создании вопроса справа гайд по созданию вопроса сделать выделяющимся на фоне остального текста. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: согласна на все 500процентов, но думаю, что это просто возможность которую представляет EnSo, а так то у RuSo не очень большой выбор, что мы можем делать, и что менять. Но это временно, пока важно отвечать и говорить свое мнение, как вы ответили, чтоб информация собиралась

Comment: @Dev18 на ruSO мне кажется нет тех ресурсов чтобы заниматься какими-то малюсенькими полосками текста которые никто не заметит и есть намного важнее вещи которые нужно отредактировать. Ну была волна когда отвечали нейросеткой, сейчас хайп на нейросетки потише стал и нет (по крайней мере я не замечаю на ruSO) ответов сгенеренных нейронкой. А если и появятся - легко заметно будет т.к люди которые разбираются в темах будут видеть бредятину которую пишет чатжпт

Comment: кстати, я наверно единственный, кто еще не знаком с этим, и благодаря одной из статей, (ответ перевод или что то) наконец поняла что это за ИИ , там как подсказка по типу, а если вы не знаете, то вот держите узнайте и примеры, так что по моему, это будет мозолить глаза и тем, кто даже не пробовал точно захочет попробовать

Comment: во, нашла https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13140/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%98%d0%98/13141#13141

Comment: ...скажу более, что к примеру на EnSo, есть стадия написания вопроса, и если не пройти первую часть то ко второй нельзя пройти и там каждая часть вопроса описывается по типу. => что вы пробовали, опишите тут итому подобная навигация, чтоб максимально даже новичка научить писать хорошие/средние вопросы, вместо того, чтоб просто минусовать и срываться на новичках, как к сожалению "пока что" происходит у нас

Comment: Любителей нейросетей можно банить, так что не прокатила аналогия с ограблением на улице.

Comment: @Зонтик при всем уважении, понимаю ваше пристрастие к желанию, учавствовать в активности сайта, даже если вы понимаете, что ответ верный, но спорить это все равно как =>(если именно по аналогии) я кроме торта не ем ничего, конечно я сладкоежка, но конфеты это не то... То есть, вы понимаете, что все эти темы с "сжечь метки""перевести то то" это все рутина, которая может подождать, ЕСЛИ ЕСТЬ КОНЕЧНО возможность сделать что то более важное. НО, мы соглашаемся на конфеты, лишь бы  чем то заняться...ПОТОМУ что важное не моГем трогать.не предлагали нам, а если мы предлагаем, то отвергают "пока что"

Comment: и то,,,даже эти темы с переводами висят месяцами, если не сказать годами(заходишь а тут перепишем переписанное.....). Но ответ как нельзя верен, и сказать тут нечего. Просто кому говорить то....тут картинка перекати поле

Comment: это ни коем образом не говорит, что неееет, нужно опустить лапки и грустить. Я тут и с вами согласна и с пользователями которые говорят, что ценим дом родной стекОверФлоу, база есть, дела есть, делаем, что дают...ценим что есть...

Comment: еще аналогия => красим дверь, которая разваливается и замок бы пора поправить;

Comment: @Зонтик так я могу вполне с помощью нейросетки генерить ответ, проверь что там адекватно всё написано, перефразировать слегка на более "человеческий" текст и отправить. Чем это будет отличаться от ответа который я напишу с 0? Вопрос философский, но для меня ответ однозначен. Банить можно тех, кто бездумно отвечает

Comment: "...например при создании вопроса справа гайд по созданию вопроса сделать выделяющимся на фоне остального текста." - если у вас есть какое-то предложение, имеет смысл задать отдельный вопрос на мете, а не добавлять в ответ на вопрос, к которому это предложение никак не относится. Предложения из ответов никто выцеплять не будет.

Comment: @insolor если бы я не написал пример почему не стоит заниматься вопросом который мы сейчас обсуждаем, то кто-нибудь написал бы "ну например чем?". А так этот аргумент - довод почему НЕ нужно ставить плашку

Comment: Так а в каком это месте аргумент? Как одно мешает другому? Почему нельзя сделать и то и другое?

Comment: Ограбление всегда умышленное, а ответы от GPT люди могут писать по незнанию, что это запрещено. Не знаю, полезна ли будет эта надпись, но аналогия действительно не работает. Это скорее как плакат "Курение запрещено" на вокзале - кто-то может из деревни приехал, и не знает, что курить нельзя.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ну по вашему же сравнению, в чем проблема даже тому кто видел этот плакат закурить? Никто не будет париться по этому поводу

Comment: За курение в неположенном месте, как и за публикацию сгенерированных ответов, предусмотрена ответственность. Если нарушаешь прямо под "плакатом о запрете", то съехать "по незнанию" не получится.

Comment: Если есть другие идеи, как сделать сайт лучше, стоит опубликовать их отдельным вопросом, а не писать их "ответом" по совершенно несвязанной теме.

Comment: Но тут смысл, чтобы ответы через ИИ не писать, а не вопросы :/

Answer (score -7):

#### Ответ более не актуален, т.к. не по теме. Оставляю здесь чисто для истории

============================================

Честно говоря я так и не понял зачем бороться с ИИ?

Как по мне если перефразировать это сообщение на что-то типа:

> Если для вопроса/ответа вы пользуютесь ИИ, то просим проверить сгенерированный текст самостоятельно, перед публикацией

, то будет намного лучше

Всё равно не остановить пользование этим ИИ, да и он иногда выдаёт достаточно полезные вещи

Comment: Ключевое "иногда". У меня был опыт, сдавал некий экзамен, так, для галочки (заставили на работе), в котором главное участие, не результат. Ну я решил заодно протестировать на реальных тестах эти GPT. Почти на каждый вопрос он мне выдавал вариантов 7 кардинально разных ответов. В итоге, только на 40% он ответил правильно, и то, я делал по 20 генераций каждого вопроса и выбирал более менее адекватные ответы. Теперь вот скажите, 60% нелепицы, по типу 2+2=7, на SO, это адекватно? Но "проверить ведь", а люди проверяют? У нас появились спецы **по всем языкам** сразу, о какой проверке речь?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Плохо это или хорошо, нравится кому-то или нет неважно, т.к. всё равно им будут пользоваться. Если писать правильные запросы и всё ему досконально разжевать, он достаточно неплохо отвечает. Что у него плохо - логика, т.е. он не способен "думать" какое-бы не было у этого слова определение, но с выдачей того что уже было известно особых проблем нет. Ставить запрет, на который всем будет плевать смысла нет, но в лишний раз перепроверить то что было сгенерировано может и помочь. В конечном счёте люди здесь за ответом, если GPT сгенерирует чушь, то другие дадут об этом знать

Comment: Опять же, я не сторонник GPT, просто не вижу смысла запрещать то, о чём щас гудит чуть ли не весь мир. Нравится или нет, приходится идти в ногу со временем и ставить запреты на такие вещи просто не несёт смысла. Я бы ещё понял это уведомление, если бы был бан юзеров, за использование ИИ, но даже этого нет. По этим причинам это уведомление для меня не больше чем ещё одна ненужная вещь на экране

Comment: "Идти в ногу со временем" - на EnSO появилась своя GPT, которая формирует ответ на поставленный вопрос, вот это вот "в ногу", и то там есть свои НО, они хотяб не портят ресурсу. Ну а ваше предложение... Как думаете, если убрать запрет на ношение оружия, на убийства, мир станет лучше? Вот примерно это вы сейчас предлагает, дать всем возможность свободно пользоваться "оружием" в виде GPT, который только в 30-40% (а то и меньше) дает адекватный ответ, а все остальное у него на уровне 2+2=7/14/3/5. Я лично не хочу при поиске нужной мне информации, получать то, что я могу и так спросить у GPT сам.

Comment: В любом случае, речь сейчас не про запрещать или нет, это уже обсуждалось много раз, даже на ruSO. Речь сейчас про упоминание о том, что GPT использовать на сайте запрещено, о чем многие новички не догадываются, удивляясь потом бану. По этому, как по мне, ваш ответ немного не по теме.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я не очень понял, так про "запрет" или про "запрещено" мы говорим?)

Comment: Довольно странный вопрос.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Полностью согласен) Но я ничего другого не придумал на ваше: "речь не про запрещать, а про то что на сайте запрещено"

Comment: *"если бы был бан юзеров, за использование ИИ, но даже этого нет"* За нарушение правил сайта вполне может быть бан. За систематическое тем более.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ На счёт оружия логичка остаётся такой же, если абсолютно у всех есть оружие кроме нас, то взять себе оружие на вооружение - очень даже хорошая идея)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Это всё крайне шаткая вещь. А что если только 20% моего ответа - это сгенерированный текст/код?) Что если код сгенерил ИИ, а я описал всё происходящее там? Им можно восползоватья как угодно и никто этого даже не заметит, я не имею ввиду тех кто просто копипастит не перепроверяя. Потому перепроверять более лучшее решение чем просто сказать что запрещено, потому что не сможете вы это запретить, разве что будете следить каждый раз при вводе текста были ли нажаты все клавиши для напечатания этого текста или нет, чего думаю никто не станет делать

Comment: Вряд ли кто-то будет проводить анализ, сколько процентов ответа было сгенерировано ИИ. Основная проблема, которую предлагается нивелировать - появление "экспертов по всем вопросам", т.е. людей, фактически не разбирающихся в теме, но (пере)публикующих ответы, которые им предоставил ИИ, под своим авторством.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Мысль здравая, но методы неправильные. Не нужно бороться с использованием ИИ, нужно бороться с тем как с ним работают. В уведомлении говорится, что: "Ответы сгенерированные с помощью ИИ инструментов не приемлимы", без всяких уточнений. Признаюсь честно, я пользуюсь ИИ, какие мой ответ некачественный (если, конечно, не учесть неопытность в начале моего пути здесь)? Всего один раз я полностью скопипастил текст ИИ и то я это явно указал и сделал только потому что там нужно было много писать, чего не сильно хотелось. ИИ довольно хороший инструмент как помощник

Comment: И потом в статье говорится, что человек и сам мог спросить у ИИ - в целом с этиим согласен, но есть 100500 способов того как задать вопрос и получать разные ответы. Спрашивать тоже надо уметь :) Я понимаю что я вряд ли кого-то переубежу в этой теме, просто поделился своими мыслями, что не стоит с ИИ бороться, стоит научить(ся) им пользовать(ся)

Comment: "Но я ничего другого не придумал на ваше" - имелось ввиду что вопрос не про запрещать или нет, ибо это и так уже решено сообществом и был вынесен вердикт, что явные GPT надо удалять, а человека за подобные нарушения в бан, об этом даже написано в справке... Вопрос про "плашку", которая оповестит человека о том, что если он напишет явный GPT - получит с большой вероятностью бан (о чем многие не догадываются). Ну а ваш ответ касается опять к "давайте не будем запрещать", а не про плашку. Надеюсь сейчас я доходчиво объяснил что имелось ввиду. Думаю дальше бессмысленно что-то тут обсуждать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Теперь стало понятнее. Действительно, я не правильно понял суть предложения и не о том спорил. Спасибо за разъяснения!