Почти ничего не изменилось, но [статус-завершено]?
Есть пост с просьбой позвать сотрудника и добавить готовые переводы и исправления в справку: Давайте уже добавим новые версии страниц в справку!
На нём висит статус-завершено, но это не так! Например, страница про закрытие вопросов не изменилась, а ведь должна была выглядеть так. Страница про очередь "Первые ответы" так и осталась без перевода, хотя он есть и был в списке.
Статья про запрет gpt осталась, но появилась ещё одна — без перевода, который уже есть и тоже был в списке!
Честно говоря, проще перечислить то, что сделано, а не то, что было забыто. Тут только три пункта будет: новая статья про gpt (но без перевода), удалена страница про очередь "Первые сообщения" и в статью про привилегию "меньше рекламы" добавлен потерявшийся абзац. А как же остальное?
Что случилось? Почему работу бросили на полпути? Мой комментарий с вопросом сотруднику так и остался без ответа.
И ещё: хочу попросить модераторов снять статус-завершено с вопроса, ведь не завершено ещё!
UPD: версия на английсокм для сотрудника тогда уже была.
UPD 2: пока статус-завершено сняли. Модератор добавил статус-проверка, ждём.

Пока не готов написать полноценный ответ здесь, но, имхо, сам вопрос довольно объёмный и сложно сформулированный. Скорее всего он был просто недопонят. Предлагаю его переформулировать, чтобы был чёткий список необходимых действий, ожидаемых от сотрудников (может быть даже сразу на английском). После этого вполне можно вернуть к [meta-tag:статус-проверка] с пингом для сотрудника.

@αλεχολυτ уже всё давно есть (кстати, на английском): https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13149/532877
